# ERROR [http-nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Incorrect syntax near 'offset'

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-order-by

query:

```
String hql = " from Reserve order by fromDate desc ";
```

error:

> ERROR [http-nio-8081-exec-2] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Incorrect syntax near 'offset'.

I am using: SQL Server 2008, hibernate 5.4.1

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: thanks...  it was org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect and i changed it to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect and problem was solved......